# google map geocode function - scope

Tags: javascript, google-maps

What is the scope of ***results*** in this statement...

```
function srPerformGeocode(address)
{       
    counter=1; 
    if (geocoder){                      
        glDelay = true;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address.trim() }, function (results, status) {            

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){                   
                // do someting 
            }
            else{
                // do someting else
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

If I add

```
var results ={};
```

in global scope, can I make it global?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global variable 
`var globalResults;` before the function creation and assign results to it. use `globalResults` any where in the program.

```
var globalResults;
function srPerformGeocode(address)
{       
    counter=1; 
    if (geocoder){                      
        glDelay = true;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address.trim() }, function (results, status) {            

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){                   
                // do someting
                 globalResults = results;
            }
            else{
                // do someting else
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The scope of `results` is the innermost function
2. not in that way, but if you change that function like so:

   ```
   var outerResult;
   ...

   geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address.trim() }, function (results, status) {           
       outerResult = results;
       ...

   });
   ```

you can access the `results` through the global `outerResult` variable.